# Swift 3D Touch Open TabBarController Not RootViewController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, 3dtouch, rootviewcontroller

I'm currently trying to add 3D touch to my app. I've already achieved that my app shows the `UIApplicationShortcutItems`, but now I'm having trouble assigning an action to them.

This is my current code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
   let homeVC = HomeVC()

   if shortcutItem.type == "com.appName.actionType1"
   {
       homeVC.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
   }

   if shortcutItem.type == "com.appName.actionType2"
   {
       homeVC.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
   }
}
```

It wouldn't be so hard to do this, but the problem I'm having is that my `HomeVC` isn't the `rootViewController`.

Any suggestions? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance of `HomeVC` each time, instead of checking for something like

```
if let homeVC = window.rootViewController as? HomeVC { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the `HomeVC` isn't the `rootViewController`

Comment: Then keep a reference to it, or at least to the tab bar controller, somewhere.

Comment: Ok, but how would I do that. That's basically what I'm trying already

Comment: You can try keeping it as a property in the app delegate.

Comment: But how, sorry I'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: In `AppDelegate.swift` add `var tabBarController: UITabBarController!` and in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` add the line `tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController`

Comment: yeah, but it is not the `rootViewController`

Comment: Then it depends on your app. You're gonna have to find a place where you have access to it and save it. I can't help you without looking at your entire project.